# Resizing images with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a test to resize images using javascript. I am working with *Flask* and my *htlm* code is the following:

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}
    {% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}
    {% block title %} - Home{% endblock %}
    {% block page_content %}

        <div class="page-header">
            <h1> Rubbish bags collected since 2016 </h1>
        </div>

        <div>
            <img id="rubbish" src="{{ url_for('.fig') }}" alt="Rubbish bags">
        </div>

        <p>Click the button to get the ID of the image.</p>

        <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

        <p id="demo"></p>

     {% endblock %}
     {% block scripts %}
     {{ super() }}
     {% endblock %}
```

The image is generated by a *Flask view function*. And the function ***"myFunction()"*** to check the ID of the image is the following:

```
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById('rubbish').id;
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = x;
    }
```

When I click on *"**myFunction()**"* the result of the ID image is *"**rubbish**"*, as expected. However, when I try to access the image to change the ***with*** property by changing the size of the windows nothing happens. Here is the javascript code:

```
    $(function() {
        if($(window).width() < 500)
        var parentwith = $('rubbish').parent().css('width');
    $('rubbish').css('width', parentwith);
    });
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($(window).width() < 500)
    var parentwith = $('rubbish').parent().css('width'); // Should be  $('#rubbish')

// If window's width is >= 500, here you'll get a "parentwith is undefined" error
$('rubbish').css('width', parentwith);
```

But why mix Javascript (`document.getElementById('rubbish')`) and jQuery (`$("#rubbish")`) together?

...but then, why do all this, just to set an image's width the same as its parent's? A simple CSS media query does the same thing and is WAY faster to execute :

```
@media (max-width: 500px){
    img#rubbish {
       width : 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that makes more sense to use css . It looks much bettter :)

Comment: Glad I could help. If my answer solved your issue, please consider validating it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are using jQuery, so to target an element by its id you need to add # , you can also use jQuery resize function to be aware of windows resize event.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById('rubbish').id;
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = x;
}
    
$(window).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() < 500) {
        var parentwith = $('#rubbish').parent().css('width');
        $('#rubbish').css('width', parentwith);
    }
});
```

```css
#rubbish {
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-header">
    <h1> Rubbish bags collected since 2016 </h1>
</div>

<div>
    <img id="rubbish" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Rubbish bags">
</div>

<p>Click the button to get the ID of the image.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

You can resize a image with Js but the better approach would be doing this with pure css using media queries or width with percentages..